# Disabling Apache compression

Tags: apache-2.2, http, compression

How do I disable Apache compression per virtual host or per directory? Is this done through a modification to the http.conf file, a .htaccess file or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922934/how-to-disable-mod-deflate-in-apache2/1923028#1923028) on stackoverflow will probably help you.

I cite:

```
# for URL paths that begin with "/foo/bar/"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/foo/bar/ no-gzip=1

# for files that end with ".py"
<FilesMatch \.py$>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
</FilesMatch>
```

So you can try something like:

```
<Directory /home/user/www>
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
[...]
</Directory>
```